# barstate.isrealtime wrongly returns true in replay mode

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I check to see if the chart is in replay mode and set a candle offset because I only want to include completed bars.

From my understanding `barstate.isrealtime` is meant to accomplish this. However when I go to replay mode for the first time I get `barstate.isrealtime` returning `false` as expected but the as soon as I go forward one bar it returns `true`. This is surely not correct. When in replay mode I would imagine all bars are historical?

```
// If Chart is realtime offset candle counts
//So not to include live bar
if (barstate.isrealtime)
    candle_offset := 1
else
    candle_offset := 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot determine if the chart is in replay mode. This is not possible.

`barstate.isrealtime` will return `true` if it is a live bar. When you add your script to your chart, it will be `false`. As soon as the price moves, it will be `true`.

Bar replay mode simulates the real-time. When you hit the "forward" the price moves as if it was real-time. Therefore, you will get `true` in bar replay mode too.